# How to pass information from parent window to child window without query string in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, dom-events

I am looking to pass information from a parent window to a child window, but cannot use a query string because there is too much information and the pop-up gets blocked. They have different domains. (cross-origin) How would I achieve this? I want the information to be passed as soon as the child window is open (the JavaScript is loaded)

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: Same origin, or cross-domain? What has your research turned up so far, what have you tried?

Comment: If same domain you can just access opener.someValue. If the opener is not available and it is on the same origin, try localStorage or sessionStorage

Comment: @misorude cross-origin. I have tried a query-string. I understand you can use an event listener, and post a message to the child window, although, the child has to be loaded (the JS has to be loaded) to receive the message through the event listener (my understanding of it).

Comment: @mplungjan is it possible to use localStorage or sessionStorage with cross-origin?

Comment: Are you in control of both sides, or do you have to make do with what the document loaded into the popup already offers? _“although, the child has to be loaded (the JS has to be loaded) to receive the message”_ - the child could as well post a message to the opening window first, “I’m ready, come at me (with the data) bro” …

Comment: Can you do something like `w.addEventListener("load",()=>{w.postMessage(...)})` so that you post message after it is loaded?

Comment: @misorude I have control of both side, but they do not have the same domain. So are you suggesting the child could post a message to the parent to say 'I am loaded' and then the parent could post a message back with the information?

Comment: @RickyMo would this be waiting for the child to load or the parent to load?

Comment: Yes, that’s what I meant. Another alternative, if you can use server-side coding on the child popup side, could be to just open the popup and then submit a hidden form to it, so that you can POST a larger amount of data than GET would allow for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Posting an "I am ready" message should work.

Parent:

```
var child = window.open(childURL);
window.addEventListener("message",(e)=>{
    if(e.data == "ready")
    {
        e.source.postMessage("some data for you","*");
    }
})
```

Child:

```
window.addEventListener("load",()=>{
    window.opener.postMessage("ready","*");
})
window.addEventListener("message",(e)=>{
    console.log(e.data);
});
```